# Is *any* linear program really a convex optimization problem?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

In *Convex Optimization* (by Boyd and Vandenberghe), the authors state that "any linear program... is a convex optimization problem" (p16). Is this really true?

Let's say we're dealing with the canonical form of the optimization problem where $f_0$ is the objective function and $f_i, (i = 1, ..., m)$ is a constraint function:

$$\min\quad f_0(x)$$
$$\text{subject to, }\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$
$$f_i(x) \le b_i$$

The authors distinguish a linear program and convex optimization problem as follows:

- In a linear program, the constraint functions $f_i$ satisfy $f_i(αx + βy) = αf_i(x) + βf_i(x)$.
- In a convex optimization problem, the constraint functions satisfy $f_i(αx + βy) \le αf_i(x) + βf_i(x)$ where $α + β = 1$, $α \ge 0$, and $β \ge 0$.

I understand that the inequality in the convex optimization problem is more general than the equality in the linear program, but the convex optimization problem also requires $α + β = 1$, $α \ge 0$, and $β \ge 0$, which all sound quite restrictive!

How can it be that "any linear program... is a convex optimization problem"? It sounds like if $α + β\neq 1$, the linear program cannot be a convex optimization problem.

Comment: It is difficult to give an answer without the book in hand. But in general, yes, linear optimization is a subset of convex optimization. And for the specific thing you mention, the constraints on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for convex optimization mean there are _less_ pairs $(\alpha, \beta)$ for which a constraint is imposed on convex optimization, so convex optimisation is actually _less_ constrained... More constraints on constraints equal less constraints.

Comment: Half spaces are convex and a linear program is the intersection of half-spaces, so it's convex.

Comment: You can think of the convexity condition as $f_i(\alpha x + (1 - \alpha) y) \le \alpha f_i(x) + (1 - \alpha) f_i(y)$. So for $\alpha \in [0, 1]$, $\alpha x + (1 - \alpha) y$ is the segment that connects $x$ and $y$, and $\alpha f_i(x) + (1 - \alpha) f_i(y)$ is the segment that connects $f_i(x)$ and $f_i(y)$.

Comment: "More constraints on constraints equal less constraints" is really helpful -- thank you. But what about the case where α+β≠1 for a linear program? Wouldn't that linear program no longer qualify to be a convex optimization problem?

Comment: @artist_and_not_EE_by_training the important property is that every two points in the region of interest contains the line segment connecting them, which is what makes it convex. This is more obvious if you write $(1-t)x+ty= x + t(y-x)$ and we can see this is 
 the line segment starting at $x$ and ending at $y$ for $t \in [0,1]$. This allows you to seek extrema by travelling along lines. In some ways convex problems are solvable because we can approximate them with linear programs by using bounding half spaces.

Comment: To follow up on @Jean-ArmandMoroni point, the $\alpha + \beta = 1$ is also a constraint on the constraint. Or better, a condition on applying the constraint. What that means is that you have to check that the $f_i(\alpha x + \beta y) \leq \alpha f_i(x) + \beta f_i(y)$ is satisfied only when $\alpha + \beta =1, \alpha \geq 0, \beta \geq 0$. When these three conditions are not met (as can happen in a general LP), then you don't have to check the convexity condition and it's fine even if it isn't satisfied.

Comment: @artist_and_not_EE_by_training This is another instance of the same thing, but reversed: this time we _add_ constraint on the linear programming side - previously we _subtracted_ constraints on the convex optimization side.

Comment: @TonyMathew is the following consistent with what you're saying? 1) If a linear program has α = 4 and β = 6, it is a convex optimization problem. 2) If the linear program happens to have α + β = 1, then fi(αx+βy)≤αfi(x)+βfi(y) must also be satisfied in order for the linear program to be considered a convex optimization problem

Comment: @artist_and_not_EE_by_training (2) is correct. Whenever $\alpha + \beta = 1$, the inequality must be checked. For (1), not really. To determine if the LP is also convex, you have to look in the space where $\alpha + \beta = 1$. If you're outside (like in your example), then we can't say whether it is or is not.  It *could be* convex. Also, keep in mind that $\alpha, \beta$ are not parameters of the LP. They're extra parameters we introduce to express the LP or convex properties. So the LP doesn't have a single value of $\alpha, \beta$

Comment: If (1) is not true, have we not found a counterexample to the statement that any linear program is a convex optimization problem?